# How to get specific rows from a document?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Suppose I have this rows inside a table:

```
<table class="lineup">
  <tbody> 
    <tr><td class="bookings"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="bookingd><span></img></span></td></tr>
...
```

how can I get only the tr that contains the img tag?

I tried:

```
  HtmlNodeCollection events = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("//table[contains(@class, 'lineup')]" +
                "//tbody//tr[contains(@td, 'img')]");
```

but this will return null

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: @TheGeneral I already use it

Comment: Problem sorted!